# MySQL: how to get an actual TimeStamp? literally the amount of seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC

Tags: mysql, timestamp

A MySQL timestamp field is written and read as 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', how can I get the actual amount of seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

> If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. date may be a DATE string, a DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the format YYMMDD or YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
```

or

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fieldGoesHere) FROM blah WHERE foo = 1;
```